# Closure downcast causes EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION fault

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

In a class I'm writing to work with WeatherUnderground, I need a number of functions all nearly identical to this function, which in this form works fineonC:

```
func currentConditions(completion: (result: WUConditionResponse?) -> Void) -> Request {
    url = urlBuilder("conditions")
    let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: Result<WUConditionResponse, NSError>) in
            completion(result: response.value)
    }
    return request
}
```

Rather than write them all separately, I tried this:

```
private typealias AFCompletion = (result: EVObject?) -> Void
private func current(command: String, onCompletion: AFCompletion) -> Request {
    let function = {(completion: AFCompletion) -> Request in
        self.url = self.urlBuilder(command)
        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, self.url)
            .validate()
            .responseObject { (response: Result<EVObject, NSError>) in
                completion(result: response.value!)
        }
        return request
    }
    return function(onCompletion)
}
```

Followed by

```
func currentConditions(completion: (result: WUConditionResponse?) -> Void) -> Request {
    let myCompletion = completion as! AFCompletion
    return current("conditions", onCompletion: myCompletion)
}
```

where `WUConditionResponse` is a subclass of `EVObject`. I then use the construct with the statement, unchanged from what was working:

```
    foo.currentConditions { (conditions: WUConditionResponse?) in
        print(conditions)
    }
```

Done this way, I get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` fault on the downcast to AFCompletion. I'm at a loss to see the problem. Why does the downcast fault? Complete answers notwithstanding, how might I debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible the way you are trying to do it. The closure you pass in

```
foo.currentConditions { (conditions: WUConditionResponse?) in
    print(conditions)
}
```

accepts ***only*** `WUConditionResponse`, one specific subclass of `EVObject`. If you cast that closure to `AFCompletion`, the resulting closure has to accept ***every*** `EVObject` which it does not.

What you *can* do is create a second only calling the `completion` if the actually passed in object is of correct type rather than casting:

```
func currentConditions(completion: (result: WUConditionResponse?) -> Void) -> Request {
    let myCompletion : AFCompletion = { res in 
        if res != nil || res! is WUConditionResponse {
             return completion(res as! WUConditionResponse?)
        }
        return false // default return
    }
    return current("conditions", onCompletion: myCompletion)
}
```

Comment: I think you're on to the problem, but the fix doesn't work. The smaller problem is that it still aborts, albeit with a different message and a SIGABT, but that notwithstanding it has the problem that stripping the type information has caused EVReflection to no longer see the elements in the WUConditionResponse and so the JSON doesn't populate it.

My original tack had been to try and build a generic as a function generator, which failed because the args didn't contain the generic's type. Learning opportunity aside, I think it may be time to go back to brute forcing it.